# Como enviar um ZonedDateTime formatado no JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, data

Eu preciso enviar o seguinte:

```
"tempo": {
    "inicio": "2019-06-24T20:00-03:00[America/Recife]",
    "fim": "2019-06-25T00:00-03:00[America/Recife]"
}
```

Criei as duas datas no meu pojo:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TempoPojo implements Serializable {
    private ZonedDateTime start;
    private ZonedDateTime stop;

}
```

E estou setando as datas dessa forma:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

TempoPojo tempoPojo = new TimeSlotPojo();

final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

calendar.setTime(model.getTempo());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
tempoPojo.setStart(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), zoneId));
```

Mas meu JSON está ficando assim:

```
"tempo":{"inicio":{"date_time":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":6,"day":24},"time":{"hour":20,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"offset":{"total_seconds":-10800},"zone":{"id":"America/Recife"}},"fim":{"date_time":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":6,"day":25},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"offset":{"total_seconds":-10800},"zone":{"id":"America/Recife"}}}}
```

Existe um forma de transformar tudo aquilo em uma data assim: `"2019-06-25T00:00-03:00[America/Recife]"`?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, lembre-se de incluir o [módulo JSR-310 do Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime), para que ele consiga lidar com as classes do `java.time`.

A seguir, configure o seguinte no `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
// adicionar o módulo java.time
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
om.registerModule(module);
// não converter o timezone
om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
```

A opção `ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` deve ser desabilitada para que não haja conversões de timezone, e ele use o que estiver no `ZonedDateTime`.

No caso do Spring, [também dá para fazer isso via *application properties*](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper#1-application-properties-and-custom-jackson-module).

E agora você tem 2 opções:

---

#### Opção 1, usar o `Serializer` *default*

Basta adicionar estas opções no `ObjectMapper`:

```
om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID, true);
```

E colocar nos seus campos:

```
@JsonProperty("inicio")
private ZonedDateTime start;

@JsonProperty("fim")
private ZonedDateTime stop;
```

Com isso, o JSON ficará assim:

```js
{
  "inicio" : "2019-06-24T20:00:00-03:00[America/Recife]",
  "fim" : "2019-06-25T00:00:00-03:00[America/Recife]"
}
```

Repare que nas horas **também são colocados os segundos**. Mas você só queria "horas:minutos", sem os segundos, então neste caso terá que criar um `Serializer` customizado.

---

#### Opção 2, usar `Serializer` customizado

Nesse caso não precisa mudar as opções `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` e `WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID`. Basta criar um `Serializer` customizado:

```
public class CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {
    private static DateTimeFormatter FMT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX'['VV']'");

    @Override
    public void serialize(ZonedDateTime value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(FMT.format(value));
    }
}
```

E nos campos, configure-os para usar esta classe:

```
@JsonProperty("inicio")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer.class)
private ZonedDateTime start;

@JsonProperty("fim")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomZonedDateTimeSerializer.class)
private ZonedDateTime stop;
```

Com isso, o JSON mostrará as horas e minutos, mas não os segundos:

```js
{
  "inicio" : "2019-06-24T20:00-03:00[America/Recife]",
  "fim" : "2019-06-25T00:00-03:00[America/Recife]"
}
```

Só verifique se é realmente isso que precisa, pois ao omitir os segundos, quem for receber esse JSON assumirá que eles são zero (geralmente as API's, ao verem que os segundos não estão presentes, setam o valor para zero - [o `java.time` faz isso](https://ideone.com/tweKo2), por exemplo). O mesmo vale para as frações de segundo.

---

Aproveitando, não precisa criar um `Calendar` para depois criar o `ZonedDateTime`.

Como você fez `calendar.setTime(model.getTempo())`, então entendo que `model.getTempo()` retorna um `java.util.Date`. Sendo assim, basta convertê-lo para `Instant` e logo depois usar `atZone` para setar o `ZoneId`.

Em seguida, para mudar o horário, use o método `with` passando um `java.time.LocalTime`. Um detalhe é que no seu código você muda a hora, minuto e segundo, porém as frações de segundo são mantidas, então tem que lembrar de mantê-los ao criar o `LocalTime`. Ficaria assim:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
// converte o Date para ZonedDateTime, usando o ZoneId indicado
ZonedDateTime zdt = model.getTempo().toInstant().atZone(zoneId);
// muda o horário (preservando as frações de segundo)
tempoPojo.setStart(zdt.with(LocalTime.of(10, 30, 30, zdt.getNano())));

// ou, você pode mudar cada campo individualmente
tempoPojo.setStart(zdt.withHour(10).withMinute(30).withSecond(30));
```

Mas como já dito acima, se você escolher a segunda opção (que não mostra os segundos no JSON), então não adianta nada setar o valor dos segundos, pois estes serão perdidos ao gerar o JSON (o mesmo vale para as frações de segundo).

Comment: Meu Json continua no mesmo formato, mesmo após as alterações... Será que não faltou mexer no meu pojo de alguma forma?

Comment: @AnandaLima Qual das opções acima vc tentou, a 1 ou a 2? Repare que em cada uma vc tem que colocar *annotations* nos campos do POJO também (`@JsonProperty` e/ou `@JsonSerialize`). Foi a única alteração que fiz

Comment: A primeira opção... Na primeira, só coloquei um JsonProperty como você sugeriu, mas acredito que isso só modifique o nome do campo no JSON, certo?

@JsonSerialize seria da segunda opção que eu ainda não tentei... OU estou esquecendo de algo na primeira? 

Meu pojo ficou assim: @JsonProperty("fim")
private ZonedDateTime stop;

Comment: @AnandaLima Bom, tem que conferir se o `ObjectMapper` foi configurado corretamente com todas as opções, se o módulo do java.time foi adicionado, etc.. Pois eu testei aqui e deu certo, talvez seja alguma dessas configurações faltando

Comment: A configuração do ObjectMapper eu deixei dentro do método que seta a minha data (a primeira parte da explicação + o om.configure da primeira opção).

As anotations que botei no Pojo foram só o jsonProperty e só coloquei a dependência no meu pom... Essas foram todas as alterações que fiz... Só penso que as configurações do ObjectMapper não possa ficar dentro do método, fora isso, está tudo igual o que você indicou.

Comment: Aqui como está tudo (nomes variáveis e métodos de demonstração apenas)
https://www.codepile.net/pile/DBvD7dLX

Comment: @AnandaLima Segue o exemplo que eu fiz, somente com as alterações que falei funciona: https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/ZonedDateTimeJsonTest#Main.java

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que você esteja usando um projeto com dependências gerenciadas pelo Maven.

Inclua a dependência **jackson-datatype-jsr310**:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
  </dependency>
```

No objeto serializável, inclua o formato desejado de data:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class TempoPojo implements Serializable {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmxxx'['VV']'")
    private ZonedDateTime start;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmxxx'['VV']'")
    private ZonedDateTime stop;

}
```

Registre o módulo JavaTimeModule no seu ObjectMapper:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TempoPojo tempoPojo = new TempoPojo();
        final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        tempoPojo.setStart(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), zoneId));      
        tempoPojo.setStop(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), zoneId));       
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(tempoPojo));
    }
}
```